# 色付き文字列をio.MultiWriterで出力するには

Tags: windows, go

以下のGo言語コードを`yellow.exe`という名前で保存していたとします

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/fatih/color"
)

func main() {
    yellow := color.New(color.FgYellow).SprintFunc()
    fmt.Fprintf(color.Output, "< %s >\n", yellow("yellow"))
}
```

それを以下のようなコードで外部プログラム実行した場合、io.MultiWriter だと色が出力されません。

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    var cmd *exec.Cmd

    cmd = exec.Command(`yellow.exe`)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Run()

    cmd = exec.Command(`yellow.exe`)
    cmd.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout)
    cmd.Run()
}
```

この例では`os.Stdout`のみを`io.MultiWriter`に入れていますが、本来はファイルへの出力と同時に標準出力にも出力したいと考えていて、ファイルには色なしで出力し、標準出力には色付きで出力したいと考えています。また、外部プログラム実行をするプログラムはgo言語とは限らず、C#で作成したプログラムの場合もあり、外部プログラム側のコードはいじれない場合もあります。その場合にどのようにすれば、標準出力に色付きの出力をしつつ、ファイルにも同じ文字列を落とせるでしょうか？

========
**追記(2018/07/10)**

@metropolis さんのコメントを受けて、さらなる調査を行ったところ、一定条件下での解決策は出たと思います。以下にそれを記しておきます。

`io.MultiWriter`を標準出力に設定すると、ターミナルではないという判定になり、`mattn/colorable` が色設定をスキップするようなので、`fatih/color` 側の `NoColor`をチェックし`true`ならエスケープ情報をそのまま標準出力に流し、親側に色情報を提供するようにしました。もし`false`なら生のターミナルにそのまま色情報を出力します。

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"

    "github.com/fatih/color"
)

func main() {
    c := color.New(color.FgYellow)
    var output io.Writer
    if color.NoColor {
        c.EnableColor()
        output = os.Stdout
    } else {
        output = color.Output
    }
    yellow := c.SprintFunc()
    fmt.Fprintf(output, "< %s >\n", yellow("yellow"))
}
```

親側はそれを受けて、標準出力は`colorable.NewColorable()`で受けて、ファイルへの出力は`colorable.NewNonColorable()`で受けてやることで、io.MultiWriterでも色設定をできるようにしました。

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"

    colorable "github.com/mattn/go-colorable"
)

var c = flag.String("c", "yellow.exe", "")

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    var cmd *exec.Cmd

    cmd = exec.Command(*c)
    cmd.Stdout = colorable.NewColorable(os.Stdout)
    cmd.Run()

    f, _ := os.Create("yellow.txt")
    defer f.Close()

    cmd = exec.Command(*c)
    cmd.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(colorable.NewNonColorable(f), colorable.NewColorable(os.Stdout))
    cmd.Run()
}
```

`親子がGo言語で書ける` 且つ `子のコードを編集可能` である場合に限り、この対応で問題ないと思いますが、これ以外の場合においては、いまだ解決策がない状態です。

Comment: https://github.com/fatih/color/blob/master/color.go#L16 を見ますと、`It's dynamically set to false or true based on the stdout's file descriptor referring to a terminal or not.` と書いてあって、その後の文言やソースコードを読む限り、yellow.go で、`c := color.New(color.FgYellow)`, `c.EnableColor()`, `yellow := c.SprintFunc()` などと書き換えると良いかもしれません。

Comment: @metropolis ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通り修正してみましたが、結果は変わりませんでした。

Comment: https://github.com/mattn/go-colorable/blob/master/colorable_windows.go#L100 でファイルディスクリプタがターミナルかチェックしているようで、私の環境はWindows ですので、https://github.com/mattn/go-isatty/blob/master/isatty_windows.go#L35 を確認したところ、`GetConsoleMode` でコンソールではないと判定されているようです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問にある追記の通り、条件付きで色付き表示ができるようになりました。現状では条件以外の解決策はないと判断し、この質問自体は解決済みにマークさせていただきます。